# Get the category of post from which category page it have been clicked

Tags: posts, categories

Look i have category1,category2,category3,category4.
Some post have got more than 1 category.
If the post is opened from category1 page i want the link and name of category1 page.
If the post is opened from category2 page i want the link and name of category2 page.
If the post is opened from category3 page i want the link and name of category3 page.
So how can we do that??